# How to deal with different categories in pytorch train, test, and holdout set

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tabular pytorch model that takes in cities and zipcodes as a categorical embeddings.  However, I can't stratify effectively based on those columns.

How can I get pytorch to run if it's missing a categorical value in the test set that's not in the train set, or has a categorical value in the holdout set that was not in the train/test set?

Answer (score 0):

u can try to use one hot encoding instead

PS: this is a suggestion not an answer

Comment: Is this what categorical embeddings do at some level?